# Why is this a tag not working inside the html tag inside sendgrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sendgrid

I am trying to send a mail via SendGrid, I never used a mail service before. This is the first time using one.

Inside your app

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(
  "*******************" // API KEY
);

const msg = {
  to: "sp@gmail.com",
  from: "berryy@gmail.com",
  subject: "Sending with sendgrid from testing site",
  text: "weofaowefnaowefinawefo",
  html: `<a> https//www.google.com </a>`,
};

try {
  sgMail.send(msg);
} catch {
  console.log('err sending mail')
}
```

As you can see I am sending a link which leads to google with a tag.
So since I am writing inside the HTML tag. It should send an **link** right but they are sending me a **string**.
Does SendGrid doesn't support links?

Comment: Don't post your api key online, you should reset it as quickly as possible

Comment: When you say "string" do you mean that the email **displays** `https//www.google.com` as a string or that it **displays** `<a> https//www.google.com </a>`, complete with tags?

Comment: @Reyno Thanks I made a beginner mistake, I actaully shorten the api by 30 words so
it shouldn't be working. The answer is pretty simple. I think I got a hot head by working long

Answer (score 1):

You didnt provide a reference.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" > https://www.google.com </a>
```